# WP REST API remove the Wordpress shortcodes from the JSON wp/v2/posts content->rendered

Tags: shortcode, api, json

I'm trying to get rid of the shortcodes that wordpress gives me when i use the WP REST API. I already managed to remove the HTML tags by editing the `class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php` by using `strip_tags()`. But i don't seem to find a solution for the short codes.

[image: example of the content i get back from the API with the shortcodes]

I tried several solutions that did not work. like write this code on the `functions.php`

```
// Removes Divi shortcodes
$content = preg_replace('/\[\/?et_pb.*?\]/', '', $content);
```

or that

```
$content = strip_tags( do_shortcode( $post->post_content ) );
```

I'm maybe doing something wrong I'm kinda new at this. if you guys could help me it would be awesome.

Comment: _Never_ edit core WordPress files. That's never the correct answer for anything.

Comment: Jacob is right, editing WP core files is one of the worst things you can do and can have disastrous consequences. Also it'll be overwritten when you next update. It's also unnecessary for what you want. It sounds like you want the fully rendered/processed content not the raw content?

Comment: yeah, exactly without the [et_pb_section....etc], just the html tags and their contents, i found a way to do it but i edited the core WordPress files, if you have a solution where i don't have to do it, it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

This is unnecessary, WordPress already provides the fully rendered HTML content in REST responses with the shortcodes already processed and turned into HTML. Inside the object the API responds with is a `content` field that has a `rendered` sub-field containing what you want. Use that instead of the raw unprocessed version.